# SQL Trigger to dump Changes to Customer Table

Tags: sql, csv, triggers, export

Hi I have looked for ways to do this but cant seem to get a clear answer. We have a requirement to Dump any changes to a table in SQL to a CSV File i.e Whenever anyone makes a change on the frontend to a customer record it must dump those changes to a CSV file for us to Update another System. Can anyone help me with an example either using SSIS or SQL Triggers.

Comment: There are numerous examples online such as http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic712960-149-1.aspx and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_triggers.htm. You should try something and get specific about what you are having issues with.

Comment: I can create the Trigger, I just do not know how to output the changes made to the table to a csv or text file.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/